# Packages with the same function name

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Libraries with the same function name in R seem to be very annoying. What is the easiest way to resolve issues like the following?

```
Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
filter, lag
The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

adding `library(stats)` or calling the filter function as `stats::filter` and the other functions as it is shown below didn't work out for me.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(stats)
stats::filter
stats::lag 
base::union 
base::setdiff 
base::setequal 
base::intersect

# Reading in the data
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header = FALSE)

# Plots 
dataSummary  <- data %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(data_count = x())
dataSummary
plotTest <- ggplot(dataSummary, aes(id, data_count)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')  + ggtitle("Test Title")
plot(plotTest)
```

But this keeps giving the previous warning message before executing the plot function. Any pointers? or is there anyway to suppress these warnings and do the plotting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. If you just don't want the warnings to show up, load the package via

   ```
   library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
   ```

   However the major downside is that it just hides the problem, it doesn't stop the execution. If you need to actually use one of the masked functions, you can call it like `stats::lag` (@alistaire).
2. Don't use packages that mask base functions. The general idea if running `example("filter")` (say) gives a different answer after loading a package is `anti-social`.
3. Some packages "improve" the base functions, so masking isn't an issue.
4. Order of loading the packages matters. First loaded package is the
   first in the search path if you are using a function that has been
   masked. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707325/meaning-of-objects-being-masked-by-the-global-environment) for some insight.

---

This answer attempted to summarise the many comments that will (eventually) deleted.