# gdata - "object is masked..."

Tags: r, gdata

I'm a newbie to R and am trying to install the `gdata` package so that I can work with excel files. When I tried to load the package, I received the following message:

```
> library(gdata) 
gdata: read.xls support for 'XLS' (Excel 97-2004) files ENABLED. 
gdata: read.xls support for 'XLSX' (Excel 2007+) files ENABLED. 
Attaching package: ‘gdata’ 
The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’: 
    nobs 
The following object is masked from ‘package:utils’: 
    object.size
```

**I'm not sure, if I should be concerned about the last two lines.** As far as I understood from other posts, they are a notice that some R functions I type in may be overridden in `gdata`, and vice-versa depending on my settings. But I see no trace of `gdata` on my screen anywhere (for example when I load JGR a new window pops up in my console). Everything looks the same as before I had loaded `gdata`. **Can you please confirm if that means I have successfully loaded `gdata`?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707325/meaning-of-objects-being-masked-by-the-global-environment has some information on this.

Comment: thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

```
print(.packages())
```

If "gdata" is inside, then the package is successfully loaded. I suspect the package has been loaded, because you got the warning message for masking.

You don't need to worry too much about masking. You can always do `gdata::nobs` and `stats::nobs` to call `nobs` function in different packages. Similarly, you can always do `gdata::object.size` and `utils::object.size` to get the right function.

Comment: I think the first part of your answer is a red herring — the question is answered by your last paragraph.

Comment: Yes, gdata is in the package. Thank you very much for the clarification as well as the hint how to deal with masking.

Comment: sorry, i'm new here :)